# ArgumentException with BuildWebHost - .Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

That's the way I've added what has been made in this article, it makes me mistake every time I try to run the website.

i have make this [here](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/):

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'XXXXXX.HelperClass.ViewRenderService' for service type 'XXXXXX.HelperClass.IViewRenderService'.'

Every time I try to drive it, there are errors here.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

But in my ConfigureService there I have added my opportunity to send email to the customer / user

```
services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
```

What can I do to prevent this error from coming back?

Comment: I tested that sample as is and it works. Are you sure you have defined `public class ViewRenderService` and not the `public abstract class `? abstract classes can't be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for help @VahidN